# What prevents consumer mini LED LCD TVs from having +2000 dimming zones?

Tags: led, lcd

In most mini LED TVs released today, the backlight can consist of thousands or tens of thousands of LEDs. Yet most of the LEDs are grouped into much less dimming zones, around a few hundred or around a thousand. It is ideal for eventually every LED to become its own independent dimming zone so that you can have a TV with tens of thousand or a hundred thousand dimming zones in order to maximize the contrast of the display and compete with self emissive displays like OLED and MicroLED. It seems like for the past few years or so, the amount of the dimming zones on these TVs has only increased marginally.

From my research, one reason is because of costs- the 1st few iterations of mini LED TVs used a passive matrix PCB substrate and a passive matrix would make it too expensive to enable much more dimming zones. However, BOE which is one of the leading LCD display manufacturers recently started mass production of mini LED LCD displays with an active matrix on glass substrate so it shouldn't be more costly to get to ten thousand dimming zones. Yet we still see their display is only limited to around 2000 dimming zones with 20,000 LEDs.

This leads me to believe that developing the backplane is not the only issue in enabling more dimming zones. I feel like the CPUs currently used in TVs are not fast enough to handle an algorithm that can process much more dimming zones.

Comment: Once you've got that many individually controlled LEDs, why would you need the LCD?

Comment: 20000 LEDs is a bit short of the 24 million pixels in a 4k TV, so you still need the LCD.

Comment: I would guess that yes, it's probably the backplane. Not only the difficulty of developing it - but also the cost of 20000 LED controllers! I bet they can't be a passive matrix - I bet that would burn out the LEDs too fast (lower duty cycle means higher peak brightness)

Comment: Likely cost. If someone did it, would you be willing to pay the premium it takes? If not, it makes no sense to make it, because no one would buy it.

Comment: @user253751 but as I mentioned, once display manufacturers use an active matrix then they don't need many ICs to control more leds independently and costs should be cheaper.https://confit.atlas.jp/guide/event-img/idw2019/AMD3-2/public/pdf_archive?type=in

Comment: _"I feel like the CPUs currently used in TVs are not fast enough to handle an algorithm that can process much more dimming zones."_ - if so that's only because they decided it wasn't necessary. Why would you want more than 2000 dimming zones?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Do you understand what haloing artifacts and blooming are? The less dimming zones there are, the more haloing artifacts and blooming there are. The point of having more dimming zones is  to increase the contrast of a display to deliver a more realistic picture. Typical Microled and OLED displays can shut off each pixel independently while in miniled-lcds it is limited to a couple thousand of zones.

Comment: You'd end up building a low-resolution monochrome display (the matrix of LEDs) behind the 'real' display (the LCD). There's no technical reason this couldn't be done - so the likely answer is that manufacturer's market research tells them that there would not be sufficient consumer demand to make the design effort & production cost-effective.

Comment: @AquaNeon active matrix means there is a controller in each LED! And unlike the screen itself, they are not created by printing semiconductors directly on a substrate - they have to be assembled from parts. (If they could be printed like that, each pixel would be its own dimming zone, and the dimming zones would be the screen with nothing in front of them, and it would be called an OLED display)

Comment: @user253751 oled displays are using organic light emitting diodes not gallium nitride based leds which are used in mini-led lcd displays and future microled displays.

Comment: @AquaNeon well the only reason they don't is that gallium nitride didn't work. They'd make gallium nitride pixels if they could